# Adapting a javascript class for interactive draggable pie charts on HTML5 canvas and integrate it in Webflow

Tags: javascript, canvas, webflow

I found this nice canvas pie on Github, but it's giving me some problem.
I'm not very good in JS, so I'm here asking for help.
https://github.com/jamesalvarez/draggable-piechart

In the example shown here, you can see a UI to manipulate the graphic.
https://codepen.io/Waterbear83/pen/vYOrbva?editors=0010

I don't understand how to display that UI even if I'm using the same js.
https://codepen.io/Waterbear83/pen/yLNqVBZ?editors=0010

Is there someone so nice to help?

Thanks!

```
  function onPieChartChange(piechart) {
      var table = document.getElementById("proportions-table");
      var percentages = piechart.getAllSliceSizePercentages();

      var labelsRow = "<tr>";
      var propsRow = "<tr>";
      for (var i = 0; i < proportions.length; i += 1) {
        labelsRow += "<th>" + proportions[i].format.label + "</th>";

        var v = "<var>" + percentages[i].toFixed(0) + "%</var>";
        var plus =
          '<div id="plu-' +
          dimensions[i] +
          '" class="adjust-button" data-i="' +
          i +
          '" data-d="-1">&#43;</div>';
        var minus =
          '<div id="min-' +
          dimensions[i] +
          '" class="adjust-button" data-i="' +
          i +
          '" data-d="1">&#8722;</div>';
        propsRow += "<td>" + v + plus + minus + "</td>";
      }
      labelsRow += "</tr>";
      propsRow += "</tr>";

      table.innerHTML = labelsRow + propsRow;

      var adjust = document.getElementsByClassName("adjust-button");

      function adjustClick(e) {
        var i = this.getAttribute("data-i");
        var d = this.getAttribute("data-d");

        piechart.moveAngle(i, d * 0.1);
      }

      for (i = 0; i < adjust.length; i++) {
        adjust[i].addEventListener("click", adjustClick);
      }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see in your JS any reference to the element with id="proportions-table" . This is referenced inside the function onPieChartChange .

Comment: @TelmoDias Because it's not created in js, it's already an element of the html. The `var table = document.getElementById("proportions-table");` refere to the existing  `<table id="proportions-table"></table>`

Answer (score 0):

> [...] even if I'm using the same js

Not quite the same :) It misses this in your setup `onchange: onPieChartChange`

```
var newPie = new DraggablePiechart({
    canvas: document.getElementById("piechart"),
    data: data,
    onchange: onPieChartChange
});
```

And then, after, in the `onPieChartChange()` there is also the `dimensions` (it's the same array but sorted randomly with the function  `knuthfisheryates2()`, like you don't have this function in your code, it throws an error `ReferenceError: dimensions is not defined` because it does not exist) term to change in `data` in the function `onPieChartChange(piechart)`. The same goes with `proportions`. But you can keep this one rather to replace it, it's handy to place common parameter like `collapsed: false` and to do operations on others like `label: d.format.label.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + d.format.label.slice(1)`

```
var proportions = data.map(function(d,i) { return {
    label: d.format.label,
    proportion: d.proportion,
    collapsed: false,
    format: {
        color: d.format.color,
        label: d.format.label.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + d.format.label.slice(1) // capitalise first letter
    }
}});
```

---

```
function onPieChartChange(piechart) {
    var table = document.getElementById("proportions-table");
    var percentages = piechart.getAllSliceSizePercentages();

    var labelsRow = "<tr>";
    var propsRow = "<tr>";
    for (var i = 0; i < proportions.length; i += 1) { // <------------------ HERE but keep --------
        labelsRow += "<th>" + proportions[i].format.label + "</th>"; // <--- HERE but keep --------

        var v = "<var>" + percentages[i].toFixed(0) + "%</var>";
        var plus = '<div id="plu-' +
        data[i] + // <----------------- HERE ------------------
        '" class="adjust-button" data-i="' +
        i +
        '" data-d="-1">&#43;</div>';
        var minus =
        '<div id="min-' +
        data[i] + // <-------------- AND HERE -----------------
        '" class="adjust-button" data-i="' +
        i +
        '" data-d="1">&#8722;</div>';
        propsRow += "<td>" + v + plus + minus + "</td>";
    }
    labelsRow += "</tr>";
    propsRow += "</tr>";

    table.innerHTML = labelsRow + propsRow;

    var adjust = document.getElementsByClassName("adjust-button");

    function adjustClick(e) {
        var i = this.getAttribute("data-i");
        var d = this.getAttribute("data-d");

        piechart.moveAngle(i, d * 0.1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < adjust.length; i++) {
        adjust[i].addEventListener("click", adjustClick);
    }
}
```

**Note:** Couldn't make it works with the angles, I looked all his examples, he never uses it, he always uses `proportions: proportions`. So I just changed that in addition in your code.

---

---

**The code is to large to be posted in a snippet here,  here a codepen:**

You can change the data from line 744 (see picture)

https://codepen.io/jghjghjhg/pen/rNVrwbd

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation and time! it looks perfect here on Codepen but when I embed it in Webflow doesn't show. Surprisingly instead his example shows in Webflow without any issue. I also tried to  validate your js checking for issues, but still not working. Do you have any idea of why this could happen?

Comment: For example, this version works perfectly fine. And I don't really understand why. I tried to override that function with the colours data, but unsuccesfully https://codepen.io/Waterbear83/pen/yLNqVBZ?editors=0010

Comment: @Umberto I tested to do the add in webflow but I'm not ableto add an embed element in the free version (it requires a paid plan), so I can't help you on this.

Comment: @Umberto Hmm... I checked the doc `custom code embed` (https://university.webflow.com/article/embed?utm_source=element-panel#in-this-lesson) it does mention that " Custom code in an embed element cannot be longer than 10,000 characters ", so it might be the reason, the whole code is over 30k characters

Comment: Yes you right about the length, in fact I had to minify the example as well. In this way it works. There must be something in the example that makes it working in webflow. For example I noticed that even if I only use the basic js (draggable-piechart.js) adding only the default piechart var newPie = new DraggablePiechart({canvas: document.getElementById('piechart')}); everything works fine on Codepen and stops working in Webflow.

Comment: This version minified works perfectly in webflow too. https://codepen.io/Waterbear83/pen/yLNqVBZ?editors=0010 And the live website here ---> https://experiencedemo.webflow.io/numerical-reasoning/numerical-reasoning-2 I'm trying to modify this version adding the different colours to the chart and not just the drawSegmentOutlineOnly

Comment: @Umberto  I can't help with the webflow issue, but I made an edit to change the title of your question and add the `Webflow` tag, it might help people more experimented on it to find about your question & help you

Comment: Thanks @Wax for your help!